# Can import certificate in london but not in N. Virginia

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to upload my *"lets encrypt"* certificate, in order to use TLS/SSL on **API Gateway**. The import process fails on *us-east-1* and does not fail *(same files, all the same...)* in london *(eu-west-2).*

The error in N. Virginia is:

> Sorry! You have reached the maximum number of certificates. Delete
>   certificates that are not in use, or contact AWS Support to request an
>   increase. Choose Previous button below and fix it.

There is no sense because i don't have any certificate yet.

**Followed steps:**

1. Import cert in London, OK!
2. I see in aws doc i need to put my cert in N. Virginia in order to use it on API Gateway
3. I remove it from ACM at london.
4. I switch to N.Virginia Region
5. Try to upload... FAIL!

What can i do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After a phone conversation *(with aws support)* we arrive at the solution.

Finally AWS increase the limit to 10 *(if i remember)* at N. Virginia.
But i do not understand why my limit is '0' by default at N. Virginia and 10 in London.

Best Regards!